# iPhone app development by an old guy

Tags: iphone

I have conceptualized an iphone/ipad app over the past 12 months. I now have all screens designed from a 'what should be on them and how should the screens work'. Now I need to add the UI Widgets to an iphone screen to get pixels and coordinates of all buttons etc.to give to my developer. I have downloaded XCode and the Interface Builder. I don't have any programming know-how (except for the course I took in fortran for a Cognate language requirement to get my Ph.D in 1975)

Is this the tool I should be using or are their others.

Where can I get a good tutorial on Interface builder. the help in the program is not good.

Any thoughts are appreciated by this old guy.

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=iphone+app+development)!

Comment: Interface Builder *should* be click-and-drag. But if you're hiring a developer to code for you, it could be easier to just give him/her drawings. I'm quite sure you can draw ovals and label things!

Comment: I agree with Blender -- it might be easier for you to get some iPhone/iPad sketch pads to give a hardcopy design to your dev.

Comment: I really hate to close this, but this is far too broad for Stack Overflow. It's my job to be 'correct' in my reasoning, and sometimes I like doing said job less than usual.

Answer (score 4):

Pay the $99 for a developer account if you haven't already, that will give you accede to the WWDC videos, they are a decent start.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't really belong here, but if you are trying to design the user interface as a wireframe, try [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/) to sketch up your design.

Comment: Sounds like the UI is finished as mockups and just needs implementing.